# Wrong tenant selected by default in VS 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, azure-cli, azure-authentication

My VS 2022 is selecting the wrong tenant by default when I log into my Azure account and I am not able to change it. I installed Azure CLI, but it seems that does not override the one VS is using.

Based on the order of authentication methods mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication?view=azure-dotnet#connection-string-support) section of the MS documentation I was able to find a workaround, that is: logging out from VS and having my right tenant set in Azure CLI.

It seems that the env variable AzureServicesAuthConnectionString (mentioned in the documentation link) does not have any effect in VS 2022, if it affected it I would be able to set the value as “RunAs=Developer;DeveloperTool=AzureCli”.

Does anyone know if there is an environment variable/configuration for this feature in VS 2022? Or maybe a way to change the current tenant for VS context?

Note: I know that I can set the correct tenant in the code itself but the problem is that it seems that I’m the only dev in my team facing this issue, all other developers have the correct tenant as the default one.

Answer (score 0):

> I installed Azure CLI, but it seems that does not override the one VS is using.

As per the [MSDoc - Sign in with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli)  , to use `Azure CLI`, we need to run the `az login` manually in the command prompt.

[image]
[image]

- Also check whether you have selected the correct tenant in Azure portal by running the `az account show` command in command prompt.

[image]

> Or maybe a way to change the current tenant for VS context?

Before setting the account try to reset all the accounts which you have logged in,

`Tools` => `Import and Export Settings`

[image]

[image]

[image]

To change the current tenant in VS, on right top of the project root directory, click on the name => `Account settings`.

[image]

[image]

- Make sure you have logged in to MS Account with correct credentials.
- Once you login with the correct credentials same will be reflected in the `Tools` => `Options` => `Azure service Authentication` => `Account Selection`.

***Initial Screen***

[image]

[image]

- Select the below option.

[image]

After validating with the correct account, `Account selection` and `All Accounts section` will be reflected with the same account.

[image]

> Does anyone know if there is an environment variable/configuration for this feature in VS 2022?

Try to add the Environment Variable as mentioned in the MSDoc which you have provided and check once.

In start menu => open `edit the system environment variables`.

[image]

- Add new environment variable as shown below.

[image]